# Upgrading Windows 8 to Pro with key only

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

I have a laptop with Windows 8. Recently I registered to Microsoft MSDNAA (or DreamSpark Premium) and can download and use Windows 8 Professional. I had problems with downloading Win8 files using Secure Download Manager (this is another issue. but it's not the point), but I obtained a valid key. Hence the question:

is it possible to upgrade from Win8 to Win8 Pro without loosing all data on pc, using just a key? My first thought was there may be some kind of Upgrade Assistant. But I don't know if it's even possible

Comment: @Alas - This is indeed possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to follow the **Add Features to Windows** procedure as outlined on the [Windows Website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/feature-packs).

> #### Add Windows 8 Pro Pack or Windows 8 Media Center Pack to your edition of Windows
>
> 1. Swipe in from the right edge of the screen, and then tap **Search**.
>
>    (If you're using a mouse, point to the upper-right corner of the screen, and then click **Search**.)
> 2. Enter **add features** in the search box, and then tap or click **Settings** .
> 3. Tap or click **Add features to Windows 8** and then do one of the following:
>
>    - If you need to purchase a product key, tap or click **I want to buy a product key online**.
>
>      Follow the steps to purchase and enter a product key.
>    - If you already have a product key, tap or click **I already have a product key**.
> 4. Enter your product key and click **Next**.
> 5. Read the license terms, select the check box to accept the license terms, and then click **Add features**.
>
> If you were running Windows 8, your PC will restart automatically and Windows 8 Pro With Media Center will be available for use.
>
> If you were running Windows 8 Pro, your PC will restart automatically and Windows Media Center will be available for use.